# SPARQL Parse Error: unexpected terminal

Tags: count, sparql, gruff

I've been using gruff to create and execute some simple SPARQL queries, but have run into some trouble. The following query works (prefixes have been left out):

```
SELECT ?k
WHERE
{ ?k  rdf:type  uw:pcservice . }
```

However, when I introduce the COUNT function, as seen below, I get the following error in gruff:

Error: Parse error: unexpected terminal ( (value: :|(|).
Expected terminals: (* varname reduced distinct).
[condition type: sparql-parse-error-unexpected-terminal]

```
SELECT (COUNT(?k) AS ?count)
WHERE
{ ?k  rdf:type  uw:pcservice . }
```

Not sure what is causing this. Any clues would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Given the error it sounds like this tool doesn't support SPARQL 1.1. It's expecting a vanilla `SELECT [*|varname|reduced|distinct]`. Try checking for a more recent version?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think you are absolutely right!

Comment: Is there a way to count in SPARQL 1.0?

Comment: No, not in standard SPARQL 1.0. A few engines had count extensions. I'd ask the gruff authors.

Comment: @user205512 could you make this an answer?

Comment: Erm, well it's just one sentence, but of course.

Answer (score 1):

Given the error it sounds like this tool doesn't support SPARQL 1.1. It's expecting a vanilla `SELECT [*|varname|reduced|distinct]`, excluding aggregates and assignment.